Why is "SEQUENCE" not valid in this postion?
So i have been giving some SQL files for some exercises that i have to do. I have tried opening the files and running them in mySQL and i get multiple errors which i don't understand. I'm using SQL version 8.0.39 which does support the use of "SEQUENCE" so i don't get why it dosen't work. When i also try to run the code below i get a similar error where it says "nextval" is not valid at its position and i don't understand why, so some help would be really appreciated.
CREATE SEQUENCE studentseq START 1;

CREATE TABLE student (
  sid INT PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT nextval('studentseq'),
  firstname VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  lastname VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  semester INTEGER,
  birthdate DATE
);

I haven't really tried much, because i don't understand why it shouldn't run. I have version 8.0.39 and according to what i knows this version does support the use of "SEQUENCE".

See the list of DDL statements supported by MySQL 8.0: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-data-definition-statements.html and notice that CREATE SEQUENCE does not appear. You may be thinking of MariaDB, which does support create sequence, but this is a different product. It is not the same as MySQL.

I think i have figured out what my problem is. I'm using MySQL which does not support it and i should really be using PostgreSQL.
